# How do i search from serialize field in mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, serialization

How do i search from serialize field in mysql database except mysql like statement?

The data is:

```
a:9:{s:2:"m1";s:4:"1217";s:2:"m2";s:8:"9986-961";s:2:"m3";s:19:"1988-03-07 00:00:00";s:2:"m4";s:0:"";s:2:"m5";s:0:"";s:2:"m6";s:0:"";s:2:"m7";s:3:"104";s:2:"m8";s:6:"150000";s :2:"m9";s:18:"Ok Then, Yes It Is";}
```

I need the row in which the m9 value is 'Yes It Is'. I do not want to use mysql 'like' statement.

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%Yes It Is%'
```

Can you please help.

Comment: Why do you not want to use the `LIKE` clause?

Comment: MySQL has no understanding of PHPs serialized format. Such `LIKE` is your only option there. Solution: split up your storage field into individual columns now that you want to SQL-query them individually after all.

Comment: suppose in the same row m8 and m9 both value is 'Yes It Is'. but i want the row whose m9 value is 'Yes It Is' not m8 value.

Comment: Using `LIKE` on columns of that sort can be cripplingly slow for large data sets. It's worth noting that Postgres has support for native JSON data which might prove a better solution in the long-term for you. It's extremely fast to query particular attributes of a JSON document, and JSON serves as a very good general-purpose serialization format.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%"m9";s:18:"Ok Then, Yes It Is";%'
```

?

But in fact if you want to search in such data, you should simple create proper structure of your table and not to put all serialized data in one column

Comment: But if the value of s is not 18 then? the like does not matches.

Comment: If answer `Ok Then, Yes It Is` is exactly the same, each time you should have `s:18` there. You can try it with other code for example: `$x['m9'] = 'Ok Then, Yes It Is'; echo serialize($x);` and you get `a:1:{s:2:"m9";s:18:"Ok Then, Yes It Is";}`

Comment: You cannot do this other way as you have the long string and you want to search inside this string. If you don't prefer like, you should create in your database column 'm9' and put there simple value for example "Ok Then, Yes It Is" and then you would be able to search using `=` operator. Otherwise it won't be possible