# How to search data in serialized php array

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am stumped upon how can i search for a specific value in serialized php array.

E.g.

i have stored days of week in a usermeta table with the key of days Available.

Now i want to show which user are available on given days via search form.

my serialized array look like this

```
a:6:{i:0;s:6:"Sunday";i:1;s:6:"Monday";i:2;s:7:"Tuesday";i:3;s:9:"Wednesday";i:4;s:8:"Thursday";i:5;s:6:"Friday";}
```

I don't want to use like % operator. any alternative will be suitable.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should unseralise it first, it will make your life a lot easier.  And if you're storing serialised data in your database, you really want to rethink your data storage strategy.  Serialised data in databases never ever ever ends well.

Comment: possibly duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508164/how-do-i-search-from-serialize-field-in-mysql-database

Comment: Yes you cant search it whilst it is serialized - so if you really have to search it you need to save the unserialized data in the db and index that.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no mysql solution to your problem. It 'might' work with `LIKE` queries for "simple" php objects, but there is no guarantee. For searching strings a `LIKE` query will always work but you have no guarantee that the string occures in the correct context.

However there is no general mysql solution. You need to unserialize the rows in php and then search in the objects/arrays itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unserialize the `a:6:{i:0;s:6:"Sunday";i:1;s:6:"Monday";i:2;s:7:"Tuesday";i:3;s:9:"Wednesday";i:4;s:8:"Thursday";i:5;s:6:"Friday";}`

then search value by `array_search('$search', $array);`