# Search table by using serialized array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to write a query using Query Builder in Laravel. I have a table named `'packages'` which is having a column `'activities'`. The column has values stored as serialized arrays. For example `a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}`. Now I want to search the table by comparing the value in 'activities' column. For example I will have an array `$arr = array(0=>2, 1=>5, 2=>1)` I want to compare it with `'activities'` column.

```
$query = DB::table('packages');
$query = $query->where('activities', $arr);
$packages = $query->get();
```

It should select all the rows that have at least one activity. ie in the above example it should select all rows that have at least 2,5 or 1 in their activities. I want the solution using Laravel Query Builder. Please help.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Instead of a varchar column maybe you should try using a JSON. https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#json-where-clauses

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i search from serialize field in mysql database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508164/how-do-i-search-from-serialize-field-in-mysql-database)

Comment: you should save these activity in comma separated value like 2,5,1 instead serialize string

Answer (score 0):

use **serialize** function

```
$query = DB::table('packages');
$query = $query->where('activities', serialize($arr));
$packages = $query->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**First you have to convert array into serialize array using [serialize() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) in php**

```
$arr = serialize($arr);

$data = $query->where([['activities', $arr], ['activities', '<>', '']])->get()->toArray();

$data = unserialize($data);

$activities = !empty($data) ? $data['activities'] : '';

@if(!empty($activities)) // check condition if activities are not empty

$result = $data; // database data 

@enfif


OR 

$data = $query->where('activities', 'like', '%' . $arr .'%')->get();
```

Comment: It should select all the rows that have at least one activity. I have updated the question.

Comment: When you want check activities not empty then pass more than one condition in where clause , check updated answer

Comment: No I mean, at least one activity that is in the $arr.

Comment: check the updated answer , you have to first get all not empty and matched data from database then check activities array as shown in updated answer

Comment: It is not working. First it showed error 'Call to a member function toArray() on array'. After I removed ->toArray(), it is showing error 'unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given'