# Select * from `transactions` where 'order_id' like "'%115%'"

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Does not return rows from serialized data  by using like operator

```
Select * from `transactions` where 'order_id' like "'%115%'"
```

Comment: Show us your sample data and expected output.

Comment: in your table order_id is a string or an integer?

Comment: Please check this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508164/how-do-i-search-from-serialize-field-in-mysql-database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking to your code you are trying to match not the coumn name but  the string 'order_id' with the string  "'%115%'"  that, obviuosly , don't match so you have no rows result  ..then

avoid single quote around column name and use concat for form  a proper like condition

```
Select * from `transactions` where order_id like concat('%', '115', '%')
```

and be sure your order_id  is string data type columns  otherwise you should use

```
Select * from `transactions` where order_id =115
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following :

1) If your order_id field is integer and you want to get exact value try this

```
SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE order_id = 115
```

2) If your order_id field is integer and you want to get matching value try this

```
SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE CAST(order_id AS CHAR) LIKE '%115%'
```

3) If your order_id field is string and stored as serialized data try this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '.*"array_key";s:[0-9]+:".array_value.".*'

ex. : SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE order_id REGEXP '.*"m5";s:[0-9]+:"115".*'
```

4) If your order_id field stored as simple string try this

```
SELECT * FROM `transactions` WHERE order_id LIKE '%115%'
```

I hope this will help you :)